# JSON to JSON Conversion using Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I am new to Jolt. I need help to generate required output. Below are Input and required
output JSON. I have written a jolt but its not generating required out put JSON.
In Input We have one items array and one Response element.
The Response Elements attribute are not being populated in Output.

**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "RegDate": "/Date(1651017600000)/",
  "Items": [
    {
      "LineItem": "1",
      "PoNumber": "1111111",
      "PoItem": "00001111"
    },
    {
      "LineItem": "2",
      "PoNumber": "2222222",
      "PoItem": "0000222222"
    },
    {
      "LineItem": "3",
      "PoNumber": "3333333",
      "PoItem": "00003333333"
    }
  ],
  "Response": {
    "GrNumber": "9999999999",
    "GrYear": "2022"
  }
}
```

**Required Output**

```json
{
  "RegDate": "/Date(1651017600000)/",
  "Items": [
    {
      "LineItem": "1",
      "PoNumber": "1111111",
      "PoItem": "00001111",
      "GrNumber": "9999999999",
      "GrYear": "2022"
    },
    {
      "PoNumber": "2222222",
      "PoItem": "0000222222",
      "GrNumber": "9999999999",
      "GrYear": "2022"
    },
    {
      "PoNumber": "3333333",
      "PoItem": "00003333333",
      "GrNumber": "9999999999",
      "GrYear": "2022"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Spec tried**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "RegDate": "RegDate",
      "Items": {
        "*": {
          "LineItem": "Items.[&1].LineItem",
          "PoNumber": "Items.[&1].PoNumber",
          "PoItem": "Items[&1].PoItem",
          "@GrNumber": "Items[&1].@GrNumber"
        }
      },
      "Response": {
        "GrNumber": "Items.GrNumber"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need more is to go two levels up the tree in order to get out `Items`, and then pick the respective values under `Response` object by using `Response.GrNumber` and `Response.GrYear` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "RegDate": "RegDate",
      "Items": {
        "*": {
          "LineItem": "&2[&1].&",
          "PoNumber": "&2[&1].&",
          "PoItem": "&2[&1].&",
          "@(2,Response.GrNumber)": "&2[&1].GrNumber",
          "@(2,Response.GrYear)": "&2[&1].GrYear"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

while

- substituting the qualifiers `Items` and `Items.` with `&2`,
- the current node values of `LineItem`,`PoNumber`,`PoItem` with `&`

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]